# Critical Failures on Attribute rolls

Tags: savage-worlds, fumbles

As it only says, in the **Savage Worlds Pathfinder** book, if you roll a 1 on both a *skill* and *wild die*, does that mean you can't **critical fail** an attribute roll and hence can reroll with a *Bennie*? Or does the standard rule book take precedence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New answer for the much-revised question.

### Partial Quote

What my copy of *Pathfinder for Savage Worlds* says is (page 118):

> A Critical Failure occurs when a Wild Card rolls a 1 on both the skill die and Wild Die of a Trait roll.

There are two noteworthy punctuation notes. First, "skill" is lower-case, indicating a common word and not a rules term (per the [Pinnacle Style Guide](https://peginc.com/store/pinnacle-style-guide-pdf/)). Second, the statement includes "Trait roll", which is a rules term that includes both Attributes and Skills.

Therefore, Critical Failures can happen on Attribute rolls when playing *Pathfinder for Savage Worlds*.

Comment: normally I would agree but there are other text difference between SWADE and SWPF, and in these cases they have been deliberate changes.

Answer (score 7):

### Misquote

*If* that was what the rules said then that would be the case. But the rules do not say that.

 *Savage Worlds*, page 88, **Critical Failure**:

> A Critical Failure occurs when a Wild Card rolls a 1 on both the Trait die and Wild Die of a Trait roll.

**Trait** is a technical term that includes both Skills and Attributes.

Comment: ah - i was looking in the SWPF book - may be I should change my question.

Comment: You may want to look for errata for your copy of PFSW - that text is supposed to be identical. If you're using a pdf, download the most recent version.

Comment: just looked in the my hard copy and the latest 1.7 version of the pdf and on page 118 it still says 'skill'. I also checked the latest v6.0  pdf of SWADE page 88 it says 'trait'.